# Is there any way to run Python on Bada?

Tags: python, bada

I'm starting developing to Bada platform. But C++ isn't my favorite language. So, is there any way to run Python on Bada?

Update: For Android there is a scpripting layer ([SL4A](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/)), and it's make possible to quickly prototype applications for android on the device itself using high level scripting languages. Is there nothing like that for Bada?

Thanks.

Comment: Meego seems your better bet with QT bindings http://wiki.meego.com/Python . I am waiting for a distro that works on the "Tab" format (like iPad)

Comment: But Meego isn't another operating system? how can an application developed for Meego can run on Bada platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible to use Python on Bada ?

In simple words No.

Applications must be written originally in C/C++/Objective-C . No third-party APIs, development tools or “code translators (e.g. from Python to C++) are allowed.

You can’t even compile very classic library such as OpenSSL or libCurl. The support of the STL is not complete

The Bada platform APIs are a lot more closed than Apple’s ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with boost::python, but Im not sure if it will work in a proper way.

Comment: This doesn't really attempt to answer the question and should probably be a comment.